# Why is my pow function returning 0 when it's being called as a variable?

Tags: c++, function

I'm new to coding and have been learning on youtube and one of the functions im learning is the pow function. When i call the function in a cout directly, it outputs the correct value, but when i use a variable to call it, it outputs 0 as the value. Am i missing a step in the declaration of the function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
      int base, exponent;
      double power = pow(base, exponent);


      cout << "What base do you have? " << endl;
      cin >> base;
      cout << "What exponent do you have? " << endl;
      cin >> exponent;
      cout << power << endl;

   return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should call `pow` *after* getting the `base` and `exponent` from the user?

Comment: `double power=pow(base, exponent)` doesn't set up some magic that updates the value of `power` whenever the value of `base` or of `exponent` are updated.   It passes the *current values* of `base` and `exponent`, at the point of declaration, to `pow()` and initialises `power` with the result.   In your code, `base` and `exponent` are uninitialised, so accessing their values (and passing them to `pow()`) causes *undefined behaviour*.    Either move the variable definition of `power` or leave it uninitialised and assign its value (`power = pow(base, exponent)`) AFTER (below) reading `exponent`,

Comment: If you want `power` to magically update when base and exponent change, you'll need to treat it as a function, in this case a *lambda*.  `auto power = [&]{ return pow(base, exponent); }` and `cout << power() << endl;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `double power = pow(base, exponent);` *after* `base, exponent` are assigned values

```
cin >> exponent;
double power = pow(base, exponent);
cout << power << endl;
```